# Can I drop table using hibernate native SQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-drop

I am trying to drop the temp table using hibernate native SQL (createSQLQuery) statement.
Here is code:

```
session.createSQLQuery("DROP TABLE tmp_dummy_table").executeUpdate();
```

However It throws me below exception:

```
SQL Error: 1003, SQLState: 24000
ORA-01003: no statement parsed

Exception while creating tmp_dummy_table tableorg.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:could not execute query
  at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152) ....
```

Could you please suggest whats wrong in this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your stacktrace it looks like you called `list()` instead of `executeUpdate()`, as you write in the code sample. Make sure you actually call `executeUpdate()`.

Comment: yeh, I found that solution and issue fixed after implimenting executeUpdate(). Thanks for suggession.